# handleNoSuchRequestHandlingMethod override not working

Tags: java, spring-mvc, overriding, http-status-code-404

```
@Controller
public class CentralizedExceptionController extends DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver {

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleNoSuchRequestHandlingMethod(NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException ex, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("working?!");
        return new ModelAndView();
    }
```

I have this in my code, but in case of a 404 its never called.
(I dont have an error-page defined in my web.xml, and i dont want to)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this jira issue: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8837?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel&focusedCommentId=72648#comment-72648

Comment: "You can create a handler, map it to all incoming request, and order as the last in line. For example implement HttpRequestHandler, map it with a SimpleUrlHandlerMapping to "/**" and set the order property of the SimpleUrlHandlerMapping to Integer.MAX_VALUE (the default). This will essentially serve as a catch all for unhandled requests." Are you able to give me an example of this? Thx

Comment: I'm sorry i can't test right now, but i hope this can give you a clue: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-simpleurlhandlermapping-example/

Answer (score 0):

If your Spring dispatcher servlet is configured to process all/most URLs, then you are probably getting the 404 error along with this DispatcherServlet log message from console:

```
No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [xxx]
```

This indicates that Spring's DispatcherServlet is processing the request but do not have an appropriate @RequestMapping to dispatch to.

A simple solution would be to limit requests processed by dispatcher servlet by reconfiguring web.xml's `servlet-mapping > url-pattern` to only URLs specified by your application's @RequestMappings. However, this is NOT very practical (so don't do this).

One way to overcome this would be to create a @RequestMapping that handles all "unhandled" request mappings - some kind of fallback request mapping.

```
@RequestMapping("**")
@ResponseBody
public String fallbackRequestMapping() {
    return "do something useful...";
}
```

Note that this answer is similar in approach to Dani's answer but written with annotation based development in mind. Therefore, it is useful to understand the associated [Spring issue](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8837).

Answer (score 0):

plz check.  Your controller class name should **not be Controller.java.**

Answer (score -1):

You need to use [`@ExceptionHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-exceptionhandler) annotation to your method:

```
@ExceptionHandler(NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException.class)
public ModelAndView handleNoSuchRequestHandlingMethod(NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException ex, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    ...
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It only works when you put this method in the same class where the 404 is created.